# Same port number on subnet

Tags: ipv4, subnet, route-server

I am in review of an IOT(Internet of Things) Project . Earlier my wifi devices were connected to a central hub which ran the webserver from an ip obtained from customer home router and on a dedicated port number .

We are thinking of removing the central box and planning to get web-servers running on each device . I would like to know since more than one device will be connected to the same router , they both will obtain ip from the same router and hence the IP addresses will be a subnet . Can both of these devices run on the same port number ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The port number is per IP address, not subnet.

The port number is in layer-4, while the IP address is in layer-3.  What a different device will connect to first is layer-3, then layer-4.  Layer-4 creates an end-to-end connection by basically combining layer-3 and layer-4 addresses.

It's like the layer-3 address is the street address of the building (host), and the layer-4 address is the room number in that building.  Multiple buildings (hosts) on the same street (subnet) can have the same room (port) number, and they are all different rooms.

Answer (score 1):

> they both will obtain ip from the same router and hence the IP addresses will be a subnet

That is not correct.  They will each obtain a unique IP address.  Both IP addreses will be in the same subnet.  Since each device in individually addressable, the servers can use the same port number.